# My Facebook acount is liking random pages throughout the day

Tags: facebook

My Facebook account old for more than 12 years and now it is getting destroyed.Right now my Facebook account is liking random pages throughout the day. So right now my homepage is full of unwanted posts and the same for stories - My account is destroyed! I have done the following steps:

- Removed all apps connected to my account.
- Removed all extensions installed in my browser.
- I have checked the active sessions and they all were safe and recognized.
- Changed my password twice.
- I have scanned my PC for viruses and it was safe.
- Logged out from my pc and I am just using my Facebook app on my Iphone.

Still, the problem exists and every 5 minutes I see from my activity log that my account has liked a random page! What can I do please and what is happening  ??

Answer (score -1):

People on Reddit have said that it has something to do with Microsoft Edge browser and AdBlock extensions - so try removing any of them and then logging out of Edge

Comment: Done and the problem still exists